Barba.js page transition: ScrollTrigger not working after navigating to a new page
I am using Barba.js for page transitions in my project, and I have some issues with ScrollTrigger after navigating between pages.
For example, when I load the homepage, the once function runs perfectly, and everything works as expected. However, when I navigate to the "About" page from the navbar, the page loads, but ScrollTrigger does not work. If I refresh the "About" page manually, everything works fine again.
barba.init({
  timeout: 5000,
  transitions: [{
    name: 'default',

    async once() {
      runAll();
      preLoader();
    },

    async enter() {
      console.log("Enter: Refreshing ScrollTrigger");
      ScrollTrigger.refresh(true);
      await runAll();
    },

    async beforeEnter() {
      console.log("Before Enter");
      console.log(ScrollTrigger.getAll()); // Check the status
      ScrollTrigger.getAll().forEach(t => t.kill());
      console.log(ScrollTrigger.getAll()); // Check the status

      console.log("Before Enter: Refreshing ScrollTrigger");
      ScrollTrigger.refresh(true);
      console.log(ScrollTrigger.getAll()); // Check the status
      await runAll(); // Reinitialize necessary functions for the new page
    },
  }]
});

I added a console.log statement in the beforeEnter function, and the final getAll() returns an empty array.
